# MPMoviePlayerController with MPMovieControlModeHidden

Tags: iphone

I am trying to hide the controls on a MPMoviePlayerController. Using:

`moviePlayer.movieControlMode = MPMovieControlModeHidden;`

Works fine on my 3GS and in the simulator, however on a 3G (running 3.1.3) it refuses to hide.

Any Suggestions?

Thanks, 
John

Comment: It's happening the same to me, on OS 4, in 3.2 it was working ok.

Answer (score 1):

you should use this code in order to hide controls :

```
player.moviePlayer.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleNone;
```